# O que é BDD e qual sua relação com o TDD?

Tags: testes, tdd, bdd

Na *web*, quando pesquisamos por **TDD**, às vezes nos deparamos também com a sigla **BDD**.

- O que é ***Behavior Driven Development (BDD)***?
- Qual a sua relação com o ***Test Driven Development (TDD)***?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### TDD

O TDD é focado no **Teste Unitário**, que significa testar cada funcionalidade dentro de todas as suas possíveis variações, para garantir que **cada parte** do todo funciona conforme esperado.

Portanto ao criar uma classe para realizar cálculos, teremos a seguinte classe

```cs
public class Calculadora () {
  public float somar (float primeiroNumero, float segundoNumero) { ... }
  public float subtrair (float primeiroNumero, float segundoNumero) { ... }
}
```

Ao criar os testes, como desenvolvedor, eu gostaria de garantir:

```
- soma de número inteiros
- soma de numeros fracionários   
- soma de números negativos
- soma de primeiro numero positivo e segundo negativo 
- soma de primeiro numero negativo e segundo positivo
```

e escreveria uma classe de testes:

```cs
public CalculadoraTests () {
  public void TestarSomaInteiros(){...}
  public void TestarSomaFrancionarios {...}
  ...
}
```

### BDD

O BDD é focado em **atender funcionalidades/comportamentos**, o que siginifica definir um cenário, definir a interação e o resultado esperado. Por exemplo:

```
Feature: Como alguém que não sabe fazer cálculos, quero que a calculadora me dê o resultados de minhas somas

  Scenario: Somar números inteiros
    Given Eu tenho uma calculadora com visor vazio
    When Eu solicitar a soma de 2 e 2
    Then Ela deve me retornar o valor 4
```

Este padrão é chamado de **Gherkin** e assim você define o comportamento (Behavior) esperado

daí basta codificar: (*exemplo em javascript pq é o que tinha aberto aqui*)

```js
var calc = new Calculadora();

this.Given(/^Eu tenho uma calculadora com visor vazio$/, function (callback) {

    calc.limpar;
    callback();
});

this.When(/^Eu solicitar a soma de (\d+) e (\d+)$/, function (num1, num2, callback) {

    calc.soma(num1, num2);
    callback();
});

this.Then(/^Ela deve me retornar o valor (\d+)$/, function (resultadoEsperado, callback) {

    assert.equal(calc.resultado(), resultadoEsperado, 'O resultado deveria ser ' + resultadoEsperado + ' mas foi ' + calc.resultado());
    callback();
});
```

Daí, com estes mesmo passos definidos posso executar diversos cenários

```
  Scenario: Somar números inteiros
    Given Eu tenho uma calculadora com visor vazio
    When Eu solicitar a soma de 2 e 2
    Then Ela deve me retornar o valor 4

  Scenario: Somar números negativos
    Given Eu tenho uma calculadora com visor vazio
    When Eu solicitar a soma de -2 e -2
    Then Ela deve me retornar o valor -4

  Scenario: Somar primeiro numero negativo e segundo positivo
    Given Eu tenho uma calculadora com visor vazio
    When Eu solicitar a soma de -2 e 2
    Then Ela deve me retornar o valor 0
```

### Conclusão

Acredito que TDD e BDD não sejam necessariamente mutuamente exclusivos, algumas regras complexas podem ser testadas unitariamente enquanto comportamentos devem ser testados como tal.

Answer (score 9):

A "jogada" do `TDD` é que existem muitos desenvolvedores focados no "como" ao escrever seus testes de unidade, de modo que eles acabaram com muito testes frágeis que não fizeram nada mais do que confirmar que o sistema faz o que faz.

`BDD` irá fornecer um novo vocabulário e, assim, concentrar-se para escrever um teste de unidade. Basicamente, é uma abordagem característica conduzido para `TDD`.
Então Basicamente `BDD` "literalmente" **é apenas** `TDD` com toda a terminologia de testes substituídos por terminologia exemplos de comportamento

Nesse [LINK](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/what-is-the-difference-between-bdd-and-tdd) tem uma questão parecida e os créditos da resposta.

[AQUI](http://caironoleto.com/2008/06/11/diferenca-entre-tdd-e-bdd/) tem outro texto explicativo sobre.

Answer (score 1):

Quero acrescentar alguns pontos que acho relevante e complementar a [resposta aceita atualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25409/95771).

---

## 2006

Neste ano, [Dan North](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) anuncia o BDD - ou como ele chama, **TDD do jeito certo** - ao mundo. Anos antes, Dan estava realizando pesquisas e análises para descobrir uma maneira de ensinar desenvolvedores tópicos como:

- O que testar e não testar?
- O quanto testar?
- Como descrever os testes?
- Como entender o porque de um teste falhar?

Desenvolvedores começam a escrever os testes pensando na falha, depois fazem-no compilar ou executar sem erros de sintaxe, criam o código de produção, fazem o teste passar e por fim refatoram os códigos. Você deve conhecer isso como TDD, mas será que isso já é o suficiente? Seguir o TDD garante uma boa suíte de testes? Se você acha que simplesmente seguir o TDD em seu projeto já basta para se considerar um ótimo escritor de testes, que seu código está tão bem documentado por testes que nem precisa de um readme, pense um pouco melhor.

## BDD

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
describe('Client', () => {
  it('Should save data into an array on success', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

<sup>Para o exemplo, me baseei na lib [jest](https://jestjs.io/), mas o conceito se aplica a qualquer linguagem ou ferramente de teste. Os códigos dos testes foram omitidos por não serem relevantes para os exemplos</sup>

O código acima lhe parece ok? Ou, você descreve testes assim?

Se a sua resposta para a primeira pergunta foi *Não*, ótimo, pois você vai entender onde o BDD se encaixa no TDD.

Tenha em mente que BDD é uma forma de pensar em como elaborar testes - de unidade, integração, end-to-end - que tem como foco o **comportamento de uma funcionalidade e não nos detalhes de implementação**. O código demonstrado acima não seria considerado um exemplo de BDD, pois ele tem detalhes técnicos de implemtação, como `data` e `array`, na descrição e provavelmente o código do teste deve ser voltado para essa validação. Ele não diz nada sobre a funcionalidade ou nada a respeito do comportamento esperado pelo domínio.

BDD propõe que os testes descrevam algo relacionado ao domínio, ao negocio, ao comportamento e não aos detalhes técnicos.

Vamos ajustar o teste acima para se encaixar no BDD:

```js
describe('Client', () => {
  it('Should send a notification to the client after product price update', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Veja só a diferença na descrição do teste. Ele informa um **comportamento** (`Should send a notification`), entidade de **domínio** (`product`) e **subdomínio** (`notification`) e **evento** (`after product price update`). Agora temos uma descrição bem clara e documentada do comportamento de uma funcionalidade que está sendo testada.

Existem alguns princípios que podem tomar como base de acordo com Dan para escrever bons testes de acordo com BDD. Vou listar os que acho mais relevantes:

1. Devemos preferir um formato de frase simples nos testes para mantê-los focados.
   Exemplo de frases:

- Ruim: ***Should send a notification to email and mobile app using SendGrid and OneSignal to the client after product price increase by 2 dollars***.
- Bom: ***Should send a notification to the client after product price update***.

2. Nomes expressivos ajudam quando os testes falham. Exemplos:

- ***Should send a notification to the client after product price update*** - podemos ter uma boa ideia de onde o teste possa falhar. Ele pode falhar no momento de enviar uma notificação ou ao atualizar o valor de um produto.

3. Prefira testar comportamento em vez da implementação.

## Só comportamento importa, então?

Eu acho super válido testar o comportamento, principalmente em testes de integração e e2e, mas em relação aos testes de unidade, testar somente o comportamento eu não acho insuficiente para garantir um código de qualidade. Teste de unidades são os mais fáceis (ou não) de implementar e rodar, pelo menos nos projetos que trabalho, então porque não testar tudo incluindo os detalhes? Isso ao menos me garante uma maior confiança em um comportamento quando os detalhes estão bem testados e validados.

Aqui vai um exemplo de teste de comportamento somente:

```js
describe('LoadAccountByToken Usecase', () => {
  it('Should return an account on success', async () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Porém, para garantir uma melhor cobertura e qualidade dos códigos testados, eu procuro testar os detalhes de implementação. Aqui um exemplo de teste que testa um detalhe de integração entre 2 componentes (a classe base e uma de suas dependências):

```js
describe('LoadAccountByToken Usecase', () => {
  it('Should call Decrypter with correct provided pass and hashed pass', async () => {
    ...
  })
})
```